# ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)

Tags: ldap, openldap

I can't add an Attribut ! can anyone help me to resolve this error !?

```
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
        additional info: 00000005: SecErr: DSID-03152612, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0
```

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the LDAP server from the times it didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP result code insufficientAccess(50) means that the currently bound identity for the LDAP connection is not allowed to apply this particular modify operation.

You did not provide any relevant details. So it boils down to:

- You have to check whether your LDAP client correctly binds to the LDAP server.
- You have to check whether the bind identity has the required access rights.